# qmake incorrect target generation

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake, qtestlib

I have a .pro file that looks like this:

```
BASEDIR = ../../..
CLEBS *= buildplugin apextools apexdata apexmain
TARGET = maintest
TEMPLATE = app
include($$BASEDIR/clebs.pri)

CONFIG *= qtestlib

QT *= testlib gui

SOURCES *= \
apexmaintest.cpp \

HEADERS *= \
apexmaintest.h \
```

But, the makefile it produces has the following targets:

```
QMAKE_TARGET  = maintest
DESTDIR       = ../../../bin/debug/
TARGET        = libmaintest.so
TARGETD       = libmaintest.so
```

Accordingly gcc produces a library. However I want an executable to be produced as specified in the .pro file.

I dont understand why this awkward thing is happening? Any pointers are appreciated.

Thank you

P.S. this is the .pro file for a unit test using qtestlib framework.

Comment: What does $$BASEDIR/clebs.pri look like?

Comment: Solved.
    CLEBS *= buildplugin
was forcing the library generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. CLEBS *= buildplugin was forcing the library generation.